# Ruby Geocoder Access Result info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I'm trying to get the state/county from a [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) method.

So right now I'm doing `result = Geocoder.search('53593')`. Which returns this:

```
Geocoder: HTTP request being made for http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=53593&language=en&sensor=false
 => [#<Geocoder::Result::Google:0x000001092deab0 @data={"address_components"=>[{"long_name"=>"53593", "short_name"=>"53593", "types"=>["postal_code"]}, {"long_name"=>"Verona", "short_name"=>"Verona", "types"=>["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Dane County", "short_name"=>"Dane County", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"Wisconsin", "short_name"=>"WI", "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address"=>"Verona, WI 53593, USA", "geometry"=>{"bounds"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>43.083595, "lng"=>-89.4592069}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>42.901066, "lng"=>-89.676706}}, "location"=>{"lat"=>42.999243, "lng"=>-89.5686271}, "location_type"=>"APPROXIMATE", "viewport"=>{"northeast"=>{"lat"=>43.083595, "lng"=>-89.4592069}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>42.901066, "lng"=>-89.676706}}}, "place_id"=>"ChIJDVeAReqQB4gR9abCGbsr3ls", "postcode_localities"=>["Fitchburg", "Verona"], "types"=>["postal_code"]}, @cache_hit=nil>] 
2.1.1 :016 >
```

Per the docs:
Every `Geocoder::Result` object, `result`, provides the following data:

```
result.latitude - float
result.longitude - float
result.coordinates - array of the above two
result.address - string
result.city - string
result.state - string
result.state_code - string
result.postal_code - string
result.country - string
result.country_code - string
```

But when I try to do `result.state` or `result.city` I get a `undefined method 'city'` error.

Any idea what I need to do to get that data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Geocoder` returns *an array* of results:

```
require 'geocoder'
result = Geocoder.search '53593'
result.class
#⇒ Array < Object
```

So, here you go:

```
result.first.city
#⇒ "Verona"
```

Comment: Should have figured that one out myself. Thanks!